# Convert a website to Android app allowing background playback

Tags: android, html, background

I want to know if there is an easy way for someone with almost inexistent coding skills to create this simple app. The only thing this app will do is act like a browser for a specific site and it will allow playback EVEN when the screen is off or the user has pressed the home button. So if a youtube video starts playing, it will be keep playing in the background if for example the user goes to another app.

Thank you very much for you app!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier and the most user-friendly way to do this is by using a front-end framework like Bootstrap...